# Waiting for ASyncTask to finish or variable to be set

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to set a variable in an activity to the result of my AsyncTask. I have read that I cannot return a variable and that I would have to set up the variable in my activity and then change it in the `onPostExecute` method.

My problem is that after the AsyncTask finishes I need to use that variable. I am having trouble with this because all the solutions I have tried so far cause the UI to freeze up and then go non-responding.

What I have tried so far:

```
while (!task.isCancelled()) {
    // Wait... 
}
```

And

```
while (variable == null) { 
    // Wait ...
}
```

Is what I am doing the best way to pass a variable from the AsyncTask to my Activity? If it is then how can I wait for the task to finish in the activity without locking up the UI?

Comment: You shouldn't be "waiting" for the `AsyncTask`. It should do something when it's done, probably in `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: In the `onPostExecute()` method I am changing the variable in my activity to the result. What I am trying to do is wait until the variable is changed.

Comment: Exactly--don't do this. The `AsyncTask`'s `onPostExecute()` itself should be starting the series of events that you want to occur after the task is complete. No other code should be relying on that task.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just put your code which you want to execute after the Variable is changed in a function and call this function from onPostExecute.

Comment: That's not a clean coding !

Answer (score 53):

If you are dependent on the result of an AsyncTask, you can do this.

```
Object result = asyncTask.execute().get();
```

The type of the result is the return type in your doInBackground() method. But then your main thread will be waiting until the task is complete.

Comment: But if you do that you will block the main thread. That is not recomendable.

Comment: adalPaRi, unless it's a splash screen?

Comment: Or a test case.